# Is it possible to delete root category?

Tags: category, catalog, ce-1.7.0.2

Is it possible to delete an empty root category once accidentally created or not required anymore? It looks like there's no "Delete" button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete a root category, if no store has been assigned to it. `Check System > Manage Stores`

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I had some store groups with `website_id` set to `0`. So they were not visible at  admin but still were locking their root categories from being deleted.